# Image Assets, Image Size, Downscaling and Memory Usage

Tags: android, image, drawable

I understand that we import different sizes of an image file into the different drawable folders (hdpi, xhdpi usw) to avoid downscaling on different screen resolutions. This costs memory and could make the image look distorted.

This is what I don't understand and i have found no proper explanation anywhere:

Does the image in pixels have to perfectly fit the containing ImageView's size or is it just important that the image comes close to it? *Because in both scenarios the process of downscaling will happen.*
Is the process of downscaling the memory intensive part or is it the size of the image file that is in the cache? For example: Is a 10% too large image better for performance than a 200% larger image?

When I prepare image assets, is it enough when they come *close* to the target size or do I have to make sure that there will be 0 scaling?

Lets say i have an ImageView with 100x100dp and an xhdpi screen draws 2 pixels for 1 dp, does my drawable have to be exactly 200x200px or can it be like 220x220px?

I talk about local images in the drawable folder here.

Comment: I am talking about the different drawable folders. hdpi, xhdpi usw

Comment: Ok, done. Thank you.